# Photoshop Gradient - where to find the RGB-Values

Tags: photoshop, rgb, gradient

i have a photoshop psd-file (opened with PS-CS4) with a new design for a website and i would like to analyse the used gradients. i found the layer responsible for the gradient and under the blending options i found the used gradient - but i am missing the exact RGB-Values for the start and end of the gradient.
Anybody could help me find those values?

Comment: Try double-clicking on the gradient in the blending options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that gradient is done by gradient option from layer blending, then follow these steps:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

[image: step 4]